# Group By Aggregation

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I have searched for similar questions and have not found a question  that allows me to group the count of an attribute with another attribute.
I have a SQL Query in this format:

```
SELECT weight, COUNT(age)
FROM patient_table
GROUP BY weight
ORDER BY COUNT(age) DESC;
```

In an elastic search database I have this information:
{"height": 170, "weight": 200, "age": 18}, {"height": 180, "weight": 250, "age": 25},...
I want to translate this SQL query to a string query in elastic search. Therefore, I want the count of the age grouped by the weight and then to return the top value.
I do not know how to pass a select statement to the elastic search query, but I have figured out how to use terms aggregation to group by weight. I assume that I can just grab the top value after it has been ordered and this will be the answer I need.
This has been my attempt thus far:

```
GET /patient_table/_search
{
    "aggs": {
        "patient": {
            "terms": {"field": "weight.keyword"},
            "order": {"_count": "desc"}
                   }
            }
}
```

EDIT: YD9's solution works, but is there anyway to create a max sub-aggregation to obtain the max value for the previous aggregations? I ask because when I try to create a sub-aggregation after the count, I get an incorrect value of null for the max_value. This is my attempt:

```
{
    "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "weigth": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "weight.keyword",
            "size": 10,
            "order": {
              "age_count_by_weight": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "age_count_by_weight": {
              "value_count": {"field": "age"}
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
          "max_age": {
              "max": {"field": "age"}
        }
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group by weight and order by the total number of ages for each weight, following query should work.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "weight": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "weight.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "age_count_by_weight": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "age_count_by_weight": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "age"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: cardinalty aggregations counts each age once. If you want to count total number of documents, this query should work:

```
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "weigth": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "weight.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "age_count_by_weight": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "age_count_by_weight": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "age"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit 2: To get max of age, you can use max_buckets aggregation. This is the sample query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "weigth": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "weight.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "age_count_by_weight": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "age_count_by_weight": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "age"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "max_age": {
      "max_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "weigth>age_count_by_weight"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to obtain the max value from this, would I just create a max sub-aggregation under age_count_by_weight? I tried to do this and I am getting the error:
"unable to parse BaseAggregationBuilder with name [age]: parser not found".

Comment: I updated the answer to find max age_count_by_weight aggregation